# How to configure Springboot backend server on Elastic Beanstalk for HTTPS without load balancer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ssl, https

I am trying too configure my Springboot web server deployed on EBS for https. As this is for a test environment I am planning to use a self-signed certificate. I have tested the application locally on postman and it works. However, after deploying the application to my EBS, ec2 instance my postman is giving:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Below are all the steps that I have taken, did I miss out on anything?

1. Creating my own SSL cert and updating my spring application properties - there should not be any issues here as it works on localhost

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/keystorename.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=alias
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

2. Allowing my security group for my EBS instance to accept HTTPS - opening port 443 for inbound
3. Http works perfectly fine, this error connection refused is only received when i enable ssl for my springboot

Note: My springboot backend is deployed using a maven installed jar application on my EBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "connect ECONNREFUSED" means that application is not running on port 443 or a firewall blocked you. you can do `telnet [ip] 443` to confirm that. If the problem is SSL, the telnet will still connect, but you will receive an error related to ssl cert

Comment: Thanks for the help, indeed the connection is refused. Does this mean that I have to make additional configurations on my ec2 or ebs? Since my application already has https enabled

Comment: you know better than me about your application. but I suspect that the application is listening on port 443. can you get into the instance and telnet to see if the port 443 is running